# servlet insde a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, taglib

I am working in Spring Framework MVC application with WebLogic server. I am using jstl 1.2. and I have a custom taglib created by me.

I have created the below Tag:

```
    public class DisplayImageTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

        private Collection<Image> images;
        private Byte[] logo;
        private String action;

        @Override
        public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {

            PageContext pc = (PageContext)getJspContext();
            JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();               
            pc.getRequest().setAttribute("test", "test");
            String fullPath = TDKUtils.getTDKPath(pc);

sb.append("<img src='" + fullPath + "/displayImage?resize=true' align='bottom' />");
out.print(sb);

        }
    }
```

I have defined this servlet, but the value of request.getAttribute("test") is `null` !  ?

```
public class DisplayImageServlet extends HttpServlet {


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println ("test ---> " + request.getAttribute("test"));
..
}
```

and the JSP

```
<tdk:displayImage logo="${logo}"    width="200" />
```

Comment: There's some missing code here... where is the JSP? What's probably happening is doGet() is called before doTag(), so test wouldn't be in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requests are different and not the same! The `DisplayImageTag` is created while creating the HTML for the Webbrowser. After receiving the HTML in the browser, the browser decides to lookup for the image from the server using a compleatly different request(not having the attribute you set for the html-request).